# Subfigures in beamer documents

Tags: latex, beamer, subfigure

I'm using beamer package to produce slides. I put many figures on a slide by using the subfigure package. The problem is that for captions, the subfigure are labeled "a", "b".. "m", "n" and so on, for subfigures appearing on different slides. How could I reset the subfigure numbering when passing to a new slide?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: added `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}` before each `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: Some better answers than the one above can be found at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/subfigures-in-beamer-documents